# Pandas how to get distinct rank when the you dont have unique counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and I only want the top 10 `count` from each device.  I figured an easy way to do this is create a new column called `rank` and then anything with a rank greater than 10 i can remove.  Here is the data:

```
        p_dt         device         namestr     count
0       2020-04-29   windows        m_outcome1  207209
1       2020-04-29   windows        m_outcome2  56599
2       2020-04-29   windows        m_outcome3  2880
3       2020-04-29   windows        m_outcome4  2879
4       2020-04-29   windows        m_outcome5  2879
... ... ... ... ...
50204   2020-04-29   web gateway    wg_outcome1 2
50205   2020-04-29   web gateway    wg_outcome2 2
50206   2020-04-29   web gateway    wg_outcome3 1
50207   2020-04-29   web gateway    wg_outcome4 1
50208   2020-04-29   web gateway    wg_outcome5 1
```

The issue that I have is if the `count` has multiple numbers that are the same per `device` then the rank is repeated several times.

`df.groupby('deviceproduct', sort=False)['count'].rank(ascending=False)`

```
0         1.0
1         2.0
2         3.0
3         5.0
4         5.0
         ... 
50204    20.5
50205    20.5
50206    23.0
50207    23.0
50208    23.0
```

When really for the same data I just want:

```
0         1.0
1         2.0
2         3.0
3         5.0
4         6.0
         ...
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider using `method=first` in your [`rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) method.

```
df.groupby('deviceproduct', sort=False)['count'].rank(ascending=False, method='first')
```

This should give you unique ranks per group.

Tested for a sample of your dataframe:

```
In [860]: df['count']                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[860]: 
0    207209
1     56599
2      2880
3      2879
4      2879
Name: count, dtype: int64

In [856]: df.groupby('device', sort=False)['count'].rank(ascending=False, method='first')                                                                                                                   
Out[856]: 
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    3.0
3    4.0 # different ranks for same value
4    5.0 # different ranks for same value
Name: count, dtype: float64
```